# how to use tfrecord by keras in tf2.x

Tags: keras, tfrecord, tensorflow2

when i using tfrecord with keras in tf2.x, it only read the first batch for training ,how can i read the remainder tfrecord data

```
def get_dataset(self,
                    tfrecord_dataset,
                    num_parallel=4,
                    batch_size=16,
                    n_epoch=1,
                    buffer_size=10000,
                    _parse_function=_default_parser):
        dataset = tfrecord_dataset \
            .map(lambda x: (_parse_function(self, x), num_parallel)) \
            .shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size) \
            .batch(batch_size) \
            .repeat(n_epoch)
        print(dataset)
        iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
        next_element = iterator.get_next()
        return next_element[0]
```

Comment: Please format your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use  `tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator` wrapped the dataset around.In tf2 ,you can use `model.fit(dataset)` directly  to train the model.